# NSUserDefaults reset

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults, reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reset the NSUserDefaults data in the iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898498/how-can-i-reset-the-nsuserdefaults-data-in-the-iphone-simulator)

Can we reset NSUserDefaults for all the keys at the same time?
Right now I reset for individual keys. So if there is a way to do that in a single go please tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Here is how to do it without looping over all values and removing them.

```
NSString *domainName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:domainName];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable code.

Comment: Yes, there is a method to do this without a loop. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9672855/257550

Comment: It is against apples recommendation to make modifications to a collection object while enumerating it.

Comment: The first Example is not resetting the userdefaults to their default values.

Comment: @ohcibi is right, +resetStandardUserDefaults; doesn't reset the userdefaults to their default value. Here is what it does: "Synchronizes any changes made to the shared user defaults object and releases it from memory."

Comment: You're all right. Deleted this part of the answer.

Comment: This doesn't work in unit tests. What worked for me was only to pass `@"xctest"` as the domain name instead.