# Delete All Prefs / Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a button in my application that will delete all entries in core data as well as all of the `NSUserDefaults`. What method would I use to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSUserDefaults reset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358737/nsuserdefaults-reset)

Comment: CoreData and User Defaults are two very different systems. Please separate these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary] forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```

resets the defaults to the registration domain, which means that removeObjectForKey is called to all the keys. I found it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545091/clearing-nsuserdefaults) link. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use for NSUserDefaults:

```
for (NSString* k in [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys])
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:k];
```