# How to remove user defaults

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reset the NSUserDefaults data in the iPhone simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898498/how-can-i-reset-the-nsuserdefaults-data-in-the-iphone-simulator)

In my project i am saving some values in NSUserdefaults with different keys.And i have reset button in my app when i click that button values stored in user defaults should remove.Is there any way to delete those values without keys,and is addSuitedNamed: and removeSuitedName can use in this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSUserDefaults * myNSUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary * dict = [myNSUserDefaults dictionaryRepresentation];
for (id key in dict) {

     //heck the keys if u need
     [myNSUserDefaults removeObjectForKey:key];
}
[myNSUserDefaults synchronize];
```

or

```
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the values of [NSUserDefault](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUserDefaults/resetStandardUserDefaults) using `resetStandardUserDefaults`.

Check this code:

```
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

Also you can:

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

Or you can use:

```
NSUSerDefaults *default = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [default dictionaryRepresentation];
for (NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys])
{
    [default removeObjectForKey:key];
}
[default synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

With a selector being called on a button click you can achieve the same using

```
- (IBAction)btnResetUserDefaultsPressed:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSDictionary* dictUserDefaults = [userDefaults dictionaryRepresentation];
    for (id akey in dictUserDefaults) {
        [userDefaults removeObjectForKey:akey];
    }
    [userDefaults synchronize];
}
```

For the second part of your question asked , You would certainly find [this](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/WorkingWithUserDefaults) useful.